# Finding element selected in NMaximize[{Min[...], constraints},{vars}]

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I determine *which* element of `Min[]` is being selected in a `NMaximize[{Min[...], constraints},{vars}]` problem? For example,

```
NMaximize[{Min[x, 1/(x - 1)], x >= 0, x <= 2}, {x}]
{1.61803, {x -> 1.61803}}
```

which is true for both elements. This is a very contrived example, though. In reality the space of elements is highly non-convex so I can't just use the answer and find the element using `Select[]`, `Position[]`, etc. for example. Somehow returning the position in `Min[]` in situ (and not post hoc) is something I was hoping for.

Addendum: I've tried using `Monitor[]` and `Trace[]` to gain some insight to what is going on but to no luck.

Comment: What about giving the different functions different units like Meter and Hour. Should be given back together with the numerical result. Can't test it now.

Comment: @Akku14 clever! Unfortunately mathematica complains about incompatible units. I really like that suggestion though of a way to tag the elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
funcs = {x, 1/(x - 1)};

{max, arg} = NMaximize[{Min @@ funcs, x >= 0, x <= 2}, {x}]

{* {1.61803, {x -> 1.61803}} *)

Select[funcs, max == (# /. arg) &][[1]]

(* x *)
```

**EDIT:** Using [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) only one function is returned due to precision issues. To identify both, [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) must be used

```
{max, arg} = Maximize[{Min @@ funcs, x >= 0, x <= 2}, {x}]

(* {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), {x -> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])}} *)

Select[funcs, max == (# /. arg) &]

(* {x, 1/(-1 + x)} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this does not work for my problem. I tried to clarify my question. I don't think any post hoc command like `Select[]` or `Position[]` will work for my case.

Comment: Please provide an example that more accurately represents the problem.

Comment: OK I will try but as stated in the question if there is a method that does this in situ instead of having to use the provided answer first the question will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

This lets you `Monitor` the value of choice. This trick is to use `;` to set a value on the LHS but return the RHS:

```
obj[x_?NumericQ] := With[{a = x, b = 1/(x - 1)},
  If[a < b, choice = 1; a, choice = 2; b]]
Monitor[
 NMaximize[{obj[x], x >= 0, x <= 2}, {x}]
 , choice]
```

Here's another example demonstrating a 3-way minimization, but now we're saving out the choice to a list of `choices`:

```
obj[x_?NumericQ] := With[{a = x, b = 1/(x - 1), c = 1/(Log[x + 1])},
  Sow[First[Ordering[{a, b, c}]]]; Min[{a, b, c}]]
choices = Reap[NMaximize[{obj[x], x >= 0, x <= 2}, {x}]][[2, 1]];
```